# Marking zero values with a red line in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a .csv datafile that outputs values from 0 to 500 i.e

```
25.2
2.82
2.05
2.13
2.42
2.17
2.00
0
0
0
0
3.33
3.41
3.26
3.30
0
27.8
```

and plot it using

```
plot 'out.csv' using 1 with lines
```

From that file I would like any 0 values to be marked on the graph with a single red line

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "a single red line"? A line from where to where? Spanning the whole y-range or just a tic an the x-axis?

Comment: A single red line from 0 to the top of the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what exactly you are looking for, the following would be my suggestion from what I understood from your question.
Plot the data again `with impulses` and filtered with the ternary operator (check `help ternary`).

**Script:**

```
### plot with ternary operator
reset session

# create some random test data
set samples 300
set table $Data
    plot '+' u (rand(0)<0.97 ? (rand(0)**20)*500+1 : 0) w table
unset table

set key out

plot $Data u 1 w l lc 1 ti "data", \
        '' u ($1==0 ? 500 : NaN) w impulses lc "red" ti "0 value"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i'm looking for i.e the red line, at the moment i plot with "plot 'out.csv' using 1 with lines" so what would i need to add to the end of this string to get the vertical red lines?

Comment: @Lurch skip the random data section and replace `$Data` with `'out.csv'`. Problem solved? Question answered?

Comment: I had already tried that and got gnuplot> plot 'out.csv' u 1 w l lc 1 ti "data",         '' u (==0 ? 500 : NaN) w impulses lc "red" ti "0 value" line 0: invalid expression

Comment: @Lurch you are missing `$1`. Maybe you are calling it from bash?! Instead you can use `... '' u (column(1)==0 ? 500 : NaN) ...`. This should work in any case.